# Cookie creation on redirection java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies, oauth

Starting with the description of what is happening.
Say I have an API `www.domain.com/login` and once the user login it redirects to `www.someOtherDomain.com` and while redirecting the response sent to someOtherDomain has a set-cookie header, having a cookie with a domain  (.domain.com). This cookie is for persisting the login session of the user on a domain (www.domain.com). But the cookie is not being set up and hence no login session is being created.

What I want to do:
I want to set the cookie on the same domain where the login page is hosted (here it would be www.domain.com) and then redirect to the someotherdomain.com.

additionals:
I am using `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView` for redirection and for setting the cookie I am using `HttpServletResponse response`

How can this be achieved in java spring boot?

Comment: You should do some reading on the same-origin cookie policy first.

Comment: I have read about the same-origin cookie policy. Still clueless. I want to set a cookie on domain ( .domain.com ) through an API hosted on domain (www.domain.com) and then redirect to (www.someotherdomain.com) and how to do it with spring boot